# Finding a polynomial $k$ respects $e^{-\epsilon k}\leq \delta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am given $e^{-\epsilon k}$ and my goal is to find a polynomial $k$ (in $\epsilon$ and $\delta$) such that $e^{-\epsilon k}\leq \delta $ where $\epsilon,\delta,k>0$. The exercise shows that $k\geq$ $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$$ln(\frac{1}{\delta})$ is the solution. However, I do not know how the book derives it. How to go from  $e^{-\epsilon k}$ to  $k\geq$ $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$$ln(\frac{1}{\delta})$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the natural logarithm on both sides: $$\ln e^{-\epsilon k}= -\epsilon k \leq \ln \delta$$

We can then divide $-\epsilon$ over and using the laws of logarithms we have the following (since we are dividing by a negative number the sign of the inequality changes from $\leq$ to $\geq$): $$k \geq -\frac{1}{\epsilon}\ln\delta = \frac{1}{\epsilon}\ln(\delta^{-1})=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\ln\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right)$$